# When to break up a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Currently I am very new to python programming, been working on it for a while, I came across a little project task which was to make a program that takes all of the vowels out of a statement so I decided to try it out. I came up with a program but it seems that it only takes out the vowels **sometimes**, I find this very weird and I would like to ask for some assistance in solving it.

```
def anti_vowel(text):
   list = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
   big_list = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
   list_word = []

   for f in text:
      list_word.append(f)

   for vowel in list:
      for letter in list_word:
         if vowel == letter:
            list_word.remove(vowel)    

   for vowel in big_list:
      for letter in list_word:
         if vowel == letter:
            list_word.remove(vowel) 


   new_word = ''.join(list_word)
   return new_word




print anti_vowel("uuuUUUUUIIIIiiiIiIoOuuooouuUOUUuooouU")
```

This statement as it sits prints out 'IiIuUUuoouU', but if I add more iterations over the lists using more for statements it decreases the amount of shown letters. Can someone tell me why this might be?

Comment: You're iterating list too many times, its not required though.

Comment: For starters `list` is a built in type in python. change the variable name of `list` to another name

Comment: You're modifying the list while you're looping over its contents.  Don't do that.

Comment: Just do it like `''.join(t for t in text if t.lower() not in vowels)`. Where `vowels` is your list (or string) containing all vowels as lower case e.g. `vowels = 'aeiou'`. When you are ready to take a step up in complexity, make `vowels` a `set` and you should improve the performance of your function.

Answer (score 0):

A little improvement:

```
list = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']

def anti_vowel(text):
    return ''.join([x for x in text if x not in list])

print anti_vowel("uuuUUUUUIIIIiiiIiIoOuuooouuUOUUuooouU")
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is the correct implementation

```
def anti_vowel(c):
    newstr = c
    vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
    for x in c.lower():
        if x in vowels:
            newstr = newstr.replace(x,"")

    return newstr
```

Comment: `newstr = c` does _not_ make a new copy of c.

Comment: Also, `('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')` is no different in performance than `'aeiou'` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Abend's solution with little edits that make it correct

```
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']

def no_vowels(str1):
    return ''.join([char for char in list(str1) if char not in vowels])

print no_vowels('finished')
```

Gives

```
fnshd

Process finished with exit code 0
```